# Value of $k$ such that $f(x) = kx$ has solutions

Tags: calculus

I have two functions $ f(x) = \exp(x^2)$ and $g(x) = kx$. I need to find values of $k > 0$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ has solutions.

Here is what I did :

- If $k < \exp(1)$, these two functions do not touch so there is no solution;
- If $k = \exp(1)$, these functions touch only once, that is, $g$ is tangent to $f$ at some point. Denote the tangent point $x_0$, then $\exp(x_0^2) = kx_0 = \exp(1)x_0$. The slopes of the two functions have to be the same at this point as they are tangent:

  $f'(x_0) = g'(x_0) <=> 2x_0\exp(x_0^2) = \exp(1)$. And so  $ \exp(x_0^2) = 2x_0^2\exp(x_0^2) <=> x_0 = 1\displaystyle /\sqrt(2)$;
- If $ k > \exp(1)$, these two functions touch two times. I don't know how to pursue from there.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean that you don't know how to pursue from there?  The statement is true, do you want to prove it, know more about it, or something else?

Comment: Who said that $k=\exp(1)$ gives only one solution?

Comment: Your k < exp(1) clause is totally wrong.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I want to prove it. 
,Holo does it not give only one solution ?
bipll Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k=0$, there is no solution. If $k<0$, the equation can also be written as
$$
\exp((-x)^2)=(-k)(-x)
$$
so we can assume $k>0$ (the case $k<0$ is symmetric).

The solution to $\exp(x^2)=kx$, if it exists, is positive, so we can as well transform the problem into $x^2=\log k+\log x$.

Consider $h(x)=x^2-\log x-\log k$ (defined for $x>0$). We have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}h(x)=\infty,\qquad \lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=\infty
$$
so $h$ has an absolute minimum. Now
$$
h'(x)=2x-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{2x^2-1}{x}
$$
only vanishes at $x=1/\sqrt{2}$. We have
$$
h(1/\sqrt{2})=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\log2-\log k=\log\frac{\sqrt{2e}}{k}
$$
The minimum is $\le0$ if and only if
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2e}}{k}\le 1
$$
that is, $k\ge\sqrt{2e}$.

The final answer is thus, keeping into account the initial discussion, that the equation has

- no solution if $|k|<\sqrt{2e}$;
- one solution if $k=\pm\sqrt{2e}$;
- two solutions if $|k|>\sqrt{2e}$.

Here is a graph for the three cases; the green function corresponds to the case $0<k<\sqrt{2e}$, the red one for $k=\sqrt{2e}$, the black one for $k>\sqrt{2e}$.

[image]

The same for $e^{x^2}-kx$:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, I just don't understand the conclusion, why does the function has no solution if $\mid k\mid < \sqrt(2e)$, one solution if....
Thank you.

Comment: @AdamElKaroui The reason for the first observation is due to the domain of the real-valued Lambert-$W$ function, which *exactly* solves $f(x) = g(x)$; for the second observation, it's because the $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ branches meet together at point $(-1/e,-1)$.

Comment: @AdamElKaroui For $k>0$, if the absolute minimum is positive, the equation has no solution; if it is $0$ there is a single solution; if the minimum is negative, there are two solutions.

Comment: @AdamElKaroui $\LaTeX$ tip: use $\{\}$ instead of $()$ for $\sqrt{} $ to get $\sqrt{whatever}$

Comment: GNU Supporter, egreg and Holo : thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @AdamElKaroui I added some graphs.

Answer (score 0):

## Analytic solution

\begin{align}
kx &= \exp(x^2) \quad (x > 0) \\
k^2 x^2 &= \exp(2x^2) \\
-k^2 x^2 &= -\exp(2x^2) \\
-2x^2 \exp(-2x^2) &= -2k^{-2} \\
-2x^2 &= W(-2k^{-2})
\end{align}

$W$ is the [Lambert-$W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Since $W(z)$ is multivalued when $z<0$, we need to pick the right branch.

- when $x \le 1/\sqrt2$,
  $$x = \sqrt{-\frac{W_0(-2k^{-2})}{2}};$$
- when $x \ge 1/\sqrt2$,
  $$x = \sqrt{-\frac{W_{-1}(-2k^{-2})}{2}}.$$

As $W$ is real-valued in this question, $-2k^{-2}$ has to be in the domain of $W$.
$$\therefore -2k^{-2} \ge -\frac1e \iff k^2 \ge 2e \iff k > \sqrt{2e} \quad (k > 0)$$

Conclusion:

- when $k < \sqrt{2e}$, there's no solution
- when $k = \sqrt{2e}$, $-2k^{-2} = -e^{-1}$, so $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ meets together, giving a unique solution $x = 1/\sqrt2$
- when $k > \sqrt{2e}$, switching between branches $W_0$ and $W_{-1} $ gives different solutions, so there are two real roots.

## Numerical verification (by [Julia](https://julialang.org))

```
using LambertW

k = sqrt(2.0*e) + 2
x = sqrt(-lambertw(-2*k^(-2), -1)/2.0)
println("k = $(k), x = $(x)")
print("k*x = $(k*x), exp(x^2) = $(exp(x^2))")
# k = 4.331643981597124, x = 1.3206259878507927
# k*x = 5.720481612214643, exp(x^2) = 5.720481612214643

k = sqrt(2.0*e) + 2
x = sqrt(-lambertw(-2*k^(-2), 0)/2.0)
println("k = $(k), x = $(x)")
print("k*x = $(k*x), exp(x^2) = $(exp(x^2))")
# k = 4.331643981597124, x = 0.245160140326756
# k*x = 1.061946446373899, exp(x^2) = 1.061946446373899
```

Comment: I'm interest in what runtime and to what accuracy this calculate the Lambert W-function, do you know this by any case?

Comment: @Holo I run this in a Jupyter notebook with Julia 0.6.2.  `display(eps())` gives `2.220446049250313e-16`, which represents the machine epsilon.  Unlike MATLAB, it's open source, so you may look at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/jlapeyre/LambertW.jl/blob/master/test/lambertw_test.jl#L78) in order to check the accuracy of `lambertw`.  From the code observed, it seems to be `1e-15`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the 2 functions:$$f(x)=\exp(x^2)\\g(x)=kx$$ Notice that for $k>0,x\le 0$ $f(x)\ne g(x)$, so we left only with positive $x$.

Let's start with no solutions, if we have no solutions and $f(0)>g(0)$ it means that $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$(by the intermediate value theorem).

So we search for some $k$ such that $\exp(x^2)>kx$, this inequality is not something we can easily solve, so before solving it let's try to find relation between this case and between the case of one solution.

If we have one solution it means that at the solution the derivatives are also equal, before the solution the derivative of $g(x)$ need to be greater and after the solution the derivative of $f(x)$ need to be greater (it is also worth noting that both of the functions not decreasing for $x>0$).

So we search for $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=g(x_0),f'(x_0)=g'(x_0), f'(x_1>x_0)>g'(x_1>x_0),f'(x_1<x_0)<g'(x_1<x_0)$, like you found in the post that $x_0=\frac1{\sqrt2}$(you have to check the other 2 conditions), using this we can find $k$:$$\exp(x_0^2)=kx_0\implies k=\sqrt{2\exp(1)}$$.

If we are decreasing $k$ we get $g(x)<\sqrt{2\exp(1)}x\le f(x)$ hence we have no solutions if $k<\sqrt{2\exp(1)}$.

Of we are increasing $k$ we have $g(x)>\sqrt{2\exp(1)}x\le f(x)$, and we have the spacial case of $x_0$: $$g(x_0)>\sqrt{2\exp(1)}x_0= f(x_0)$$.

We can show that if $k>\sqrt{2\exp(1)}$  we have exactly $2$ solutions by the fact that $g''(x)=0$

---

For negative $k$ we just ignore the positive $x$'s and do the exact same thing